# Speechbubble tooltip in CSS - how to move the arrow

Tags: html, css, tooltip

Hey there i created this little speech bubble tooltip, where the arrow is at the bottom:

http://jsfiddle.net/QNPYQ/

```
.bubble:after {
    border-color: #EEEEEE rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 26px;
    bottom: -52px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    left: 4em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
```

Anybody could tell me how to make the arrow at the top of the `<div>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could rotate the arrow and place it according to top

```
.bubble:after {
    border-color: #EEEEEE rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 26px;
    top: -52px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    left: 4em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/QNPYQ/1/

Comment: Seems a bit unnecessary to rotate the whole thing instead of just changing the order of the border-colors, no?

Comment: Indeed @Hecksa I would prefer your solution but it's still an altrenative way to achieve this :)

Answer (score 5):

http://jsfiddle.net/a2ZFF/

You need to change the border-colour to point the arrow the other way, and it also makes sense to render the border :before rather than :after (though this is not absolutely necessary).

```
.bubble:before {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) #EEEEEE;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 26px;
    content: "";
    top:-53px;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    left: 4em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
```

To make the whole thing fit in, you'll then need to add a top margin to the whole thing, or some similar adjustment.